# Generic inference in constructors

Tags: java, generics

If I have a class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo<T> {
    public Foo(T t) {
        //do something
    }

    public static <E> void bar(E e) {
         //do something
    }
}
```

Why does `Foo.bar("String");` infer that `E` is a String (and therefore not throw a compiler warning) but `new Foo("String");` not infer that `T` is a String?

Comment: What is the precise error you are seeing?

Comment: @linuxuser27 You get a raw type warning on `new Foo("String");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the constructor can be considered a special instance method, it is not typed - it gets its type from the class name (with a type parameter),eg `Foo<String>`. ie the constructor is not defined as:

```
public <T> Foo(T t) ...
```

nor can it be. Doing so would *hide* the generic type of the class (and you'll get a warning)

The static method however *is* typed. FYI, the generic-parameter-less call, once the type is inferred, is equivalent to:

```
Foo.<String>bar("String");
```

Comment: +1.  Very interesting, but I still don't see why in this instance it can't be inferred by a similar mechanism from the argument list

Comment: Have you noticed this: If you declare your class like this: `class TestClass<T>` and your constructor `public <E> TestClass(T t)` you don't get an warning, but if you do this: `class TestClass<T>` and your constructor `public <T> TestClass(T t)` you get a compiler warning stating "The type parameter T is hiding the type T"

Comment: @Varun Achar You can declare [generic constructors](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html), and if you redeclare <T> on a constructor you are indeed hiding the class' <T>. I believe boehemian is trying to say is that since I am not creating a generic constructor, it is inheriting it's type from the class, not the other way around. But it still leaves a question of why the class can't infer the type parameter from a constructor.

Answer (score 3):

When Java implemented generics, it was decided that a generic class instantiated without type parameters would always return a raw-type. This differs from generic methods missing type parameters, which the compiler tries to infer the type of. From the Java Tutorials:

> Generally, the Java compiler can infer the type parameters of a generic method call. Consequently, in most cases, you do not have to specify them.

But when discussion turns to constructors:

> Note that to take advantage of automatic type inference during generic class instantiation, you must specify the diamond. In the following example, the compiler generates an unchecked conversion warning because the HashMap() constructor refers to the `HashMap` raw type, not the `Map<String, List<String>>` type:
>
> `Map<String, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap(); // unchecked
>   conversion warning`

source: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html

This remains the same in Java 7, however they tried to make it less repetitive by supporting diamond syntax. For example, `Foo<String> foo = new Foo<>("String")`. See [this section of the same article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypeinference.html#type-inference-constructors).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to do this

```
new Foo<String>("String");
```

to tell get the generics info passed; similar to the Collections API.

Comment: That is correct.  The OP is not asking 'what' needs to be done but 'why', since in the fact of a static method call this is not needed.

Comment: What linuxuser said, doing `new Foo<String>("String");` seems repetitive when you're already passing a `String` to the constructor.

Comment: I think it's going to be less repetitive in Java 7.

Comment: In Java 7 you can do this: `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` . The type is inferred automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into this, I am going to take a guess here.  Consider the following:

```
public class Foo {
    public <E> Foo(E t) {
        //do something
    }

    public static <E> void bar(E e) {
         //do something
    }
}
```

In the above class you get no warning when instantiating `Foo` as follows:

```
Foo f = new Foo("String");
```

This works because the type of `E` is being inferred here.  Just as you expect it to happen in the method case.  However the error you are getting is not because the argument type is not being inferred, but because the raw type for the class cannot be inferred.

I think what this comes down to is that the Class raw type can propagated to the methods, but the methods cannot set the class raw type using inference.

Comment: I believe this is what Bohemian was getting at. Since you don't declare the class' type parameter, the constructor isn't given a type.

Comment: @Jeffrey - I agree. This was great question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@Kublai Khan's answer is correct; the type of `new Foo(s)` is raw `Foo`, for backward compatatability.

Java7's constructor diamond type inference ( `new Foo<>(s)` ) is the same as, and defined in term of, method type inference on method.

[http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~darcy/ProjectCoin/ProjectCoin-Documentation-v0.9375.html#diamond](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Edarcy/ProjectCoin/ProjectCoin-Documentation-v0.9375.html#diamond)

> If the class instance creation expression uses "<>" to elide class type arguments, a list of methods m1...mk is defined for the purpose of overload resolution and type argument inference...
>
> ...then one of m1...mk is selected, using the process described in §15.12.2 (Determine Method Signature)

Your suspicion is correct, constructors can use inference just like methods, there are no essential differences. You just have to add `<>` due to backward compatibility issue.

Why did it take Java 6 years to add this feature is another story.